# Deleting duplicate lines from a bunch if HTTP links

Tags: duplicates, rtf

Here is an example of HTTP links in a rtf document:

`servername.com/projectname/actual/done`

`servername.com/jobname/actual/done`

`servername.com/jobname/actual/done`

`servername.com/titlename/actual/done`

`servername.com/partname/actual/done`

`servername.com/jobname/actual/done`

`servername.com/accessoryname/actual/done`

`servername.com/jobname/actual/done`

`servername.com/jobname/actual/done`

`servername.com/partname/actual/done`

`servername.com/accessoryname/actual/done`

I would like to delete every duplicate lines with some tool or script

Result would be

`servername.com/projectname/actual/done`

`servername.com/jobname/actual/done`

`servername.com/titlename/actual/done`

`servername.com/partname/actual/done`

`servername.com/accessoryname/actual/done`

I know some methods in Notepad++, but it would be nice to have some little file with a script for this.

Answer (score 0):

under bash you can simply do

```
cat filename.txt | sort | uniq
```

that will give you each unique line. But I guess you will have to convert it to text first if the file is RTF or equivalent format.